# How can I test if a variable is empty or contains only spaces?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, string

The following bash syntax verifies if `param` isn't empty:

```
 [[ !  -z  $param  ]]
```

For example:

```
param=""
[[ !  -z  $param  ]] && echo "I am not zero"
```

No output and its fine.

But when `param` is empty except for one (or more) space characters, then the case is different:

```
param=" " # one space
[[ !  -z  $param  ]] && echo "I am not zero"
```

"I am not zero" is output.

How can I change the test to consider variables that contain only space characters as empty?

Comment: From `man test`: `-z STRING - the length of STRING is zero`. If you want to remove all spaces in `$param`, use `${param// /}`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767644/bash-test-if-string-has-non-whitespace-characters

Comment: **WOW** there is not a simple `trim()` function built-in to any *nix at all? So many different hacks to achieve something so simple...

Comment: @ADTC $(sed 's/^\s+|\s+$//g' <<< $string) seems simple enough to me. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Because it could be shinier

Comment: Just noting that `[[ !  -z  $param  ]]` is equivalent to `test ! -z $param`.

Comment: There is a hackinsh way, if you drop BASH '[[' it will actually work, but for the wrong reason.
`! [ -z $param ] 2>/dev/null && echo no content`
'[' as a program will ignore multiple spaces between arguments and will fail if wrong number of arguments is provided with a result '1'. The same as if test -z was false. There is a special case of second argument '-o', but besides that, I would also argue against using it as even if its "working", it's not doing what it's intended to do.

Comment: @Noah `[` is equivalent to `test`. Sometimes it used to be a symlink. But `[[` is BASH specific and there are many differences to program `test`. The reason of creating [[ was to make it easier to construct conditions. For that purpose it can't be the same as '[' or `test`.

Answer (score 374, accepted):

First, note that the [`-z` test](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) is explicitly for:

> the length of string is zero

That is, a string containing only spaces should **not** be true under `-z`, because it has a non-zero length.

What you want is to remove the spaces from the variable using the [pattern replacement parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
[[ -z "${param// }" ]]
```

This expands the `param` variable and replaces all matches of the pattern  (a single space) with nothing, so a string that has only spaces in it will be expanded to an empty string.

---

The [nitty-gritty of how that works](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) is that `${var/pattern/string}` replaces the first longest match of `pattern` with `string`. When `pattern` starts with `/` (as above) then it replaces *all* the matches. Because the replacement is empty, we can omit the final `/` and the `string` value:

> ${parameter/pattern/string}
>
> The *pattern* is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. *Parameter* is expanded and the longest match of *pattern* against its value is replaced with *string*. If *pattern* begins with ‘/’, all matches of *pattern* are replaced with *string*. Normally only the first match is replaced. ... If *string* is null, matches of *pattern* are deleted and the / following *pattern* may be omitted.

After all that, we end up with `${param// }` to delete all spaces.

<sub>Note that though present in `ksh` (where it originated), `zsh` and `bash`, that syntax is not POSIX and should not be used in `sh` scripts.</sub>

Comment: use `sed` they said... just `echo` the variable they said...

Comment: Hmm. If it is `${var/pattern/string}` then shouldn't it be `[[ -z ${param/ /} ]]` with the space between the slashes to be the pattern and nothing after to be the string?

Comment: @JesseChisholm "Because the replacement is empty, we can omit the final / and the string value"; "If *string* is null, matches of *pattern* are deleted and the / following *pattern* may be omitted."

Comment: @MichaelHomer The answer `[[ -z "${param// }" ]]` sure looks like the `pattern` is empty and the `replacement string` is a single space. AH! I see it now `if pattern begins with a slash` I missed that part. so the pattern is `/ ` and the string is left off and therefore empty. Thanks.

Comment: bash note: if running in set -o nounset (set -u), and param is unset (rather than null or space-filled), then this will generate an unbound variable error.  ( set +u; ..... ) would exempt this test.

Comment: This approach will not catch **multi-line variable** with spaces. Try xargs instead: `[[ -z $(echo $var | xargs) ]]`

Comment: Yes ${myVar// } works. Also ${myVar%%*( )} and ${myVar##*( )} and ${myVar##+( )} and its because if we remove leading, trailing or all spaces in a string it will become empty if it only contains spaces.

Answer (score 39):

The easy way to check that a string only contains characters in an authorized set is to test for the presence of unauthorized characters. Thus, instead of testing whether the string only contains spaces, test whether the string contains some character other than space. In bash, ksh or zsh:

```
if [[ $param = *[!\ ]* ]]; then
  echo "\$param contains characters other than space"
else
  echo "\$param consists of spaces only"
fi
```

“Consists of spaces only” includes the case of an empty (or unset) variable.

You may want to test for any whitespace character. Use `[[ $param = *[^[:space:]]* ]]` to use locale settings, or whatever explicit list of whitespace characters you want to test for, e.g. `[[ $param = *[$' \t\n']* ]]` to test for space, tab or newline.

Matching a string against a pattern with `=` inside `[[ … ]]` is a ksh extension (also present in bash and zsh). In any Bourne/POSIX-style, you can use the `case` construct to match a string against a pattern. Note that standard shell patterns use `!` to negate a character set, rather than `^` like in most regular expression syntaxes.

```
case "$param" in
  *[!\ ]*) echo "\$param contains characters other than space";;
  *) echo "\$param consists of spaces only";;
esac
```

To test for whitespace characters, the `$'…'` syntax is specific to ksh/bash/zsh; you can insert these characters in your script literally (note that a newline will have to be within quotes, as backslash+newline expands to nothing), or generate them, e.g.

```
whitespace=$(printf '\n\t ')
case "$param" in
  *[!$whitespace]*) echo "\$param contains non-whitespace characters";;
  *) echo "\$param consists of whitespace only";;
esac
```

Comment: This is *almost* excellent - but, as yet, it does not answer the question as asked. It currently can tell you the difference between an unset *or* empty shell variable and one which contains only spaces. If you will accept my suggestion you will add the param expansion form not yet convered by any other answer that explicitly tests a shell variable for being set - I mean `${var?not set}` - passing that test and surviving would ensure that a variable matched by your `*)` `case` would effect a definitive answer, for example.

Comment: Correction - this, in fact, *would* answer the question originally asked, but it has since been edited in such a way that it fundamentally changes the meaning of the question and therefore invalidates your answer.

Comment: You need `[[ $param = *[!\ ]* ]]` in `mksh`.

Answer (score 25):

POSIXly:

```
case $var in
  (*[![:blank:]]*) echo '$var contains non blank';;
  (*) echo '$var contains only blanks or is empty or unset'
esac
```

To differentiate between *blank*, *non-blank*, *empty*, *unset*:

```
case ${var+x$var} in
  (x) echo empty;;
  ("") echo unset;;
  (x*[![:blank:]]*) echo non-blank;;
  (*) echo blank
esac
```

`[:blank:]` is for horizontal spacing characters (space and tab in ASCII, but there are probably a few more in your locale; some systems will include the non-breaking space (where available), some won't). If you want vertical spacing characters as well (like newline or form-feed), replace `[:blank:]` with `[:space:]`.

Comment: POSIXly is ideal because it will work with the (arguably better) dash.

Comment: `zsh` seems to have problem with `[![:blank:]]`, it raise `:b` is invalid modifier. In `sh` and `ksh` emulate, it raise event not found for `[`

Comment: @cuonglm, what did you try? `var=foo zsh -c 'case ${var+x$var} in (x*[![:blank:]]*) echo x; esac'` is OK for me. The event not found would only be for interactive shells.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Ah, right, I tried with interactive shells. The `:b` invalid modifier is a bit strange.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Anyway, I expect it works in emulate `sh` and `ksh`, whether interactive or not. Any ideal?

Comment: @cuonglm, I can't reproduce the :b thing. What version of zsh, what command line?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: zsh version 5.2, command `case $1 in ([![:blank:]]) echo 1;; esac`

Comment: On my machine `[:blank:]` only match a single space, not a tab. I read that it is locale specific?

Comment: @FranklinYu, that would be possible but unheard of. What system is it? What locale? Does `bash -c "case $'\t' in [[:blank:]]) echo yes; esac"` really _not_ output `yes`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas My bad. I thought `'\t'` suffices, because I tested it with `echo`. However on OS X, `echo` by default interpretates the ANSI-C escapes, for both Zsh and Bourne shell (but not Bash, so maybe the Bourne shell is faked by Zsh) in interactive mode. Now my issue becomes `[:space:]` not including `$'\n'` or `$'\v'`.

Comment: @FranklinYu, on OS/X `sh` is `bash` built with `--enable-xpg-echo-default` and `--enable-strict-posix-default` so as to be Unix compliant (which involves `echo '\t'` outputting a tab).

Answer (score 7):

*The only remaining reason to write a shell script, instead of a script in a **good** scripting language, is if extreme portability is an overriding concern.*  The legacy `/bin/sh` is the only thing you can be certain you have, but Perl for instance is *more* likely to be available cross-platform than Bash.  Therefore, never write shell scripts that use features that aren't *truly universal* -- and keep in mind that several proprietary Unix vendors froze their shell environment *prior to POSIX.1-2001*.

There is a portable way to make this test, but you have to use `tr`:

```
[ "x`printf '%s' "$var" | tr -d "$IFS"`" = x ]
```

(The default value of `$IFS`, conveniently, is a space, a tab, and a newline.)

(The `printf` builtin is itself spottily portable, but relying on it is much less hassle than figuring out which variant of `echo` you have.)

Comment: That's a bit convoluted. The usual portable way to test whether a string contains certain characters is [with `case`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147109).

Comment: @Gilles I don't think it's possible to write a `case` glob to detect a string which is either empty, or contains *only* whitespace characters. (It would be easy with a regexp, but `case` doesn't do regexps. The construct in your answer won't work if you care about newlines.)

Comment: I gave spaces as an example in my answer because that's what the question asked for. It's equally easy to test for whitespace characters: `case $param in *[![:space:]]*) …`. If you want to test for `IFS` characters, you can use the pattern `*[$IFS]*`.

Comment: @Gilles - that is true, and mostly well-put, but your answer still fails entirely to determine certainly whether a variable is *either* empty or that it consists *only* of space characters because, as is, it currently cannot reliably distinguish between an *empty* and an *unset* shell variable.

Comment: @Gilles `[[:charclass:]]` is not a feature you can use under the portability constraints I described above (i.e. "truly universal"). I don't know, but I very strongly suspect `*[$IFS]*` is also unreliable.

Comment: @Zack `[[:charclass:]]` is POSIX, but not supported by , and risky because it's locale-dependent. `*[$IFS]*` would work in any shell, why do you think it would be unreliable?

Comment: @Gilles - `*[$IFS]*` does have a problem if it is set to a value other than that for which you mean to match. And that's the same problem this answer has - it's just a variable like any other. Strange that it should go to such great lengths to achieve two decades worth of portability, and then rely on a variable's value which it does not set explicitly. In what locale does `[[:space:]]` not evaluate to `<space>` `<tab>` and `<newline>`?

Comment: @Gilles I know it's not supported by older Solaris /bin/sh, at least (what did you have in mind?) I don't know either way, but I wouldn't trust shells that old to do variable expansion *at all* inside case globs.

Comment: @mikeserv In a really _seriously_ defensive script, you explicitly set IFS to `<space><tab><newline>` at the beginning and then never touch it again.  I thought that'd be a distraction.

Comment: You should use it to split as needed, but I agree that it is better to be explicit.

Comment: @Zack I remember seeing otherwise-POSIX shells that didn't support character classes but I forget which (maybe older OpenBSD without much locale support if any?). BusyBox includes support for them but it's probably a compilation option (I haven't checked).

Comment: Regarding variables in patterns, I think that works in all Bourne versions and all POSIX shells; it would require extra code to detect case patterns and turn off variable expansion and I can't think of a reason to do it. I have a couple of instances of it in my `.profile` which has been executed by many Bourne shells. Of course `[$IFS]` won't do what was intended if `IFS` has certain non-default values (empty (or unset), containing `]`, starting with `!` or `^`).

Comment: Regarding the reason behind using shell script, it is the best scripting language to interact with other system tools and scripting actual terminal-based workflow. You can't just throw the language out the window and criticize everyone who uses it just because it doesn't apply to you.

Comment: @Jean-LucNacifCoelho Please just try using a different scripting language for everything that you would normally write shell scripts for, for a couple months.  I bet you will come around to my point of view.

Answer (score 5):

```
if [[ -n "${variable_name/[ ]*\n/}" ]]
then
    #execute if the the variable is not empty and contains non space characters
else
    #execute if the variable is empty or contains only spaces
fi
```

Comment: this gets rid of any white space character, not just a single space, right? thanks

Answer (score 1):

For testing if variable is empty or contain spaces, you can also use this code:

```
${name:?variable is empty}
```

Comment: I think your answer is downvoted because the "or contain spaces" is not true.

Comment: be careful - that kills the current shell. Better to put it in a (: ${subshell?}). Also - that will write to stderr - you probably want redirect. And *most important* that evaluates to the variable's actual value if it is not unset or null. If there's a command in there, you just ran it. It's best to run that test on `:`.

Comment: how it will kill shell. and u can also test this , first define `name=aaaa` then run this command `echo ${name:?variable is empty}` it will print value of variable name and now run this command `echo ${name1:?variable is empty}` it will print **-sh: name1: variable is empty**

Comment: Yes - `echo ${name:?variable is empty}` will either evaluate to `$name`'s non-null value *or* it will kill the shell. So for the same reason you don't do `prompt > $randomvar` neither should you `${var?}` - if there's a command in there, it's probably going to run - and you don't know what it is. An interactive shell doesn't have to exit - which is why yours doesn't. Still, if you want to see some tests, there are a lot of them [here.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120008/52934). [This one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146027/52934) isn't quite as long...

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted `[[ !  -z  $param  ]] && echo "I am not zero"` will print `I am not zero` if param is either unset/undefined or empty (in bash, ksh and zsh).

To **also** print if param contains only spaces (remove spaces), POSIXly (for a wider range of shells):

```
 [   -z "${param#"${param%%[! ]*}"}"   ] && echo "empty"
```

Explanation:

- A `${param# … }` removes a **leading** text.
- That leading text is given by: `${param%%[! ]*}`
- Which expands to **all spaces before** any **non-space** character, i.e. all the leading spaces.

The end result of the whole expansion is that all leading spaces get removed.

This expanded result is tested if of length 0.

- If the result is empty, then either the variable was empty, or
- removing the leading spaces made it empty.

Therefore, if the test is true, the variable was either empty already or only had spaces inside it.

---

The concept is easy to extend to more character types. To also include tabs, place an explicit tab inside the bracket expression:

```
 [ -z "${param#"${param%%[!     ]*}"}" ] && echo "empty"
```

or use a variable with the characters that you need removed:

```
 var=$' \t'                                    # in ksh, bash, zsh
 [ -z "${param#"${param%%[!$var]*}"}" ] && echo "empty"
```

or you can use some POSIX "character class expression" (blank means space and tab):

```
 [ -z "${param#"${param%%[![:blank:]]*}"}" ] && echo "empty"
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if variable has only spaces, including in a **multi-line variable**, try this:

```
[[ $var = *[$" \t\n"]* ]]
```

Or with xargs:

```
[[ -z $(echo $var | xargs) ]]
```

Or with sed:

```
[[ -z $(sed "/^$/d" <<< $var) ]]
```

Comment: There are a lot of non-blank values of `$var` for which `[[ -z $(echo $var | xargs) ]]` would return true, like `-n`, `-e \x20`, `"" '' \ \ \ ""`, etc, not to mention all the issues related to globbing.

Comment: You're confusing `$"..."` with `$'...'`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the solution without trimming

```
BLANK_STRING_REGEX='^ *$'
TEXT="  "
if [[ $TEXT =~ $BLANK_STRING_REGEX ]] ; then
    echo "Blank string"
fi
```

I've also noticed that it's often useful to check whether a string contains spaces and new line chars only:

```
BLANK_STRING_REGEX='^\s*$'
TEXT="  
    
"
if [[ $TEXT =~ $BLANK_STRING_REGEX ]] ; then
    echo "Blank string"
fi
```

Comment: Note that bash uses the system's regexp API to do regexp matching. `\s` is not a standard regexp operator, so that won't work on all systems. The standard equivalent is `[[:space:]]` (and `[[:blank:]]` for the `\h` equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
echo ${param//*[^[:space:]]*/I am not zero}
```

Answer (score -1):

I prefer this:

```
[[ $(echo "$param" | awk '{print NF}') -eq 0 ]]
```

Comment: awk would also consider tabs as "empty", not just spaces. Also see: [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373)

Comment: There are also [potential problems with using `echo` on arbitrary data](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/117549).

Comment: That would also not work properly for variables containing newline characters.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$ [[ -z \`echo $n\` ]] && echo zero

zero
```